# PNG images with hot spots?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a few full screen png's where I want to create regions on the images such that when a user clicks on one of the regions, a specific png dissolves in to replace the current image.  I'm creating sort of a slide show but I might have 3 or 4 active regions that cause different images to appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techniques for doing this have not changed much: use an imagemap or place transparent elements over the image and give them a click event.